# Fetching data from the table using python and mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, apache, xampp, localhost

I am using "python3.4" and "Mysql.connector" used to connect database.And accessing the Xampp Mysql ,running the code in local host .
Below given code is what i used to connect databse and fetch data

```
  #!"C:\python34\python.exe"
    import sys
    import mysql.connector
    print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
    print()

    /* code to connect datbase*/
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',port='8051',
                                           database='test',
                                           user='root',
                                           password='Tom')
    cursor = conn.cursor()                                 
    if conn.is_connected():
        print('sucessfull...Connected to MySQL database')
    cursor.execute(" SELECT * FROM testtable1 ")
print ("<html>")
print("<p>")
print("hai")
print("</p>")
print("<body")
print ("<table border='2'>")
print ("<tr><td>")


for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print (row)
print ("</td></tr>")
print  ("</table>")
print ("</body>")
print ("</html>")
```

Output it's giving as :
    sucessfull...Connected to MySQL database

I am not able to display data inside table .without table also it's unable to print the data whatever fetched from the table .
running the code in localhost as http://localhost:804/cgi-bin/test.py
Is any problem because of xampp or apache .
Please give some suggestion

Comment: @evans_murithi  i edited plz see

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    for row in cursor.fetchall()
        print(row[1])
```

To read more about it, see this [site](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-query/)

Comment: change `print(row[1])` to `print(row)`

Comment: same result,its not working.I think it's fetching data but it is not printing problem in displaying .

Comment: Try adding e.g. `<p>some text</p>` somewhere in between the html tags, Plus remove the `<head>` tag. Include the `<table>....</table>` in the `<body>..</body>`